# How to put a <a> link inside a <span> that is in a <a>?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href, html

Here my  code

```
  <a href="http://linkurl" class="link" title="sometitle">
 text link 

 <span class="hidden-tooltip-data" style="display: none;"> <a
 href="http://www.google.ca"> my link here destroy everything </a 
</span>
  </a>
```

I use Poshy   here script

```
       $('.link').each(function() {
      var tooltip = $(".hidden-tooltip-data",this).html();
      $(this).attr("title","");
    $(this).poshytip({
    content: function(updateCallback) {
        return tooltip;
             }
         });
      });
```

Comment: You should never put an `<a>` inside of another `<a>`, no matter what. You also don't explain what it is you're trying to do, you just throw a bunch of code at us.

Comment: this is wrong, why do you want to do that way?

Comment: Your question does not make sense ....

Comment: The question does make sense; even if what he wants to do is completely incorrect. Explaining him why is a good answer in any case.

Comment: Serving some "food for thought" for us ?

Comment: well, the question is clear dunno why somebody gave a -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nested links are illegal**. This case is explicitly mentioned in [the HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't be doing that. The reason resides in the fact that the child `a` is completely ignored because it's under the parent `a`.

I suggest you just making a `span` that contains two different `a` tags that contain as many `span` as required.

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** put a link inside another link.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Poshytip will read an element's `title` attribute and use that as the tooltip content.  However, you want to include a link in the tip, and putting HTML in the `title` would look ugly if JavaScript is turned off (and be inaccessible).

Your best approach would be to include a text-only `title` for downlevel browsers and include the enhanced tip content in a `data` attribute (obvously escaping markup):

```
<a href="..." class="link" title="basic content" data-tip="enhanced content &lt;a href=&quot;...&quot;&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;">...</a>
```

```
$('.link').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title','').poshytip({ content: $(this).data('tip') });
});
```

Including markup in an attribute like that obviously gets a little messy, so if your tips have a common format, it might be a better idea to include the URL as the `data` attribute and build the markup in script.

```
$('.link').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title','').poshytip({ content: '<a href="' + $(this).data('tiplink') + '">link</a>' });
});
```